# Debug play framework app in prod mode

Tags: playframework-2.0

How do I connect a JPDA debugger to a Play 2.0 app running in production mode?

I'm using production mode for development (typing "start") because of a deadlock bug in dev mode in Play 2.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just using dev mode and killing the process each time, because the deadlock bug doesn't seem to appear on the first run.